# How to access Soundcloud JSON data

Tags: json, soundcloud

I'm experimenting with the soundcloud API and try to extract **all playlist titles** from my JSON object, to make a list with references. Actually I don't have many experience with JSON and therefore I just can't manage to call any variable form the decoded JSON array...

http://api.soundcloud.com/users/55607614/playlists.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID

I already did take a look on the structure via http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ but it didn't really help me out...

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.soundcloud.com/users/55607614/playlists.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID"));
echo $json[??][??]...;
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#

Comment: https://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud

Comment: I already had a look on the sdk, but don't really know which functionality could help me out.

Comment: do you wanna use your json result in php or javascript? basically you need to count the results and iterate through each object to access the relevant information you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
private SCPlaylistObject playListObject, plTestObject;
public string TrackList;
private List<SCTrackObjects> TListTest;

/// <summary>
/// Deserializes JSON data into object from string
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="jsonString"></param>
    /// <returns>json object</returns>
    public static T Deserialize<T>(string jsonString)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer deserializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));

        MemoryStream MemStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(jsonString));

        T result = (T)deserializer.ReadObject(MemStream);

        return result;


    }


public  async Task<string> GetUserTracks() // Async Call to get user id
    {
        try
        {
            responseText = await GetjsonStream();

            SCUserID = userObject.id;

            TrackList = await GetTracks();


            TList = Deserialize<List<SCTrackObjects>>(TrackList);

            return TrackList;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
            Console.Out.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return ex.Message;
        }


public async Task<string> GetTracks() //Function to read from given url
 {
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    string url = SCLink + SCAPIUsers + SCUserID + "/tracks?client_id=" + soundcloudAPI;
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
    HttpResponseMessage v = new HttpResponseMessage();
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  }
}

    public async Task<string> GetjsonStream() //Function to read from given url
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string url = SCLink + SCAPIUsers + SCNameField + ".json?client_id=" + soundcloudAPI;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        HttpResponseMessage v = new HttpResponseMessage();
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer, "just code" is not enough (also the formatting is a bit off).